# How to echo special characters

Tags: php, html

I am using the Steam OpenID API to retrieve usernames. The problem is some users have names like this:

> █Ỏ͖็✪3░⠀็Ỏ͖͈̞̩͎̻̫̫̜͉̠̫͕█

but when the username is inputed into the webpage this is what the username looks like:

> â–ˆá»ŽÍ–à¹‡âœªsw3ðŸ”˜tâ–‘â €à¹‡á»ŽÍ–ÍˆÌžÌ©ÍŽÌ»Ì«Ì«ÌœÍ‰Ì Ì«Í•â–ˆ

I couldn't find a solution to this problem, but if someone could manage to find the solution, please link it in the answer.

Comment: use header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

Comment: @Dave Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/5626245/dave

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$message="!@#%&^*()%^%%$";

 echo htmlentities($message); 

?>
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".